# How to texture a model in LWJGL?

Tags: lwjgl, blender, texture-mapping

I have created some chess piece models, I created them in Blender, successfully exported as OBJ and loaded into my LWJGL program. They display correctly with lighting and color, etc. (YEAH!!)

Now, being chess pieces, I would like it to have a wood texture. (Wood grain lines, etc, like a chess piece).

It is my understanding that this should be accomplished via textures (makes sense...), but I can only find examples that texture quads. The most prevalent example seems to be applying one texture to the 6 sides of a cube, using glTexCoord2f to define the corners of the texture.

However, I want to texture my model, a large mesh of triangles.

How would I go about applying one wood grain image over an entire model?

Thanks!!

Side note: if you're familiar with Blender, the effect I want is the same as when you add a material to the model, then add an image texture to the material.

Comment: usually you do it inside the model editor (maya, blender..), there you put on the texture and defining the UV map coordinates between the texture and the model. when exporting an obj file it exports the texture coordinates too, and you read the texture coordinates the same way you read the other coordinates. google it.

Comment: Ah! That makes sense. I will try that today and get back with my results/further questions. Thanks!!!

Comment: Still confused, found this resource that seems really good. I'll read this and learn more about OpenGL, will post an answer if I ever figure this out. http://www.glprogramming.com/red/about.html

Comment: also I don't know much about 3d textures and how to use them, it should look very good on object like chess pieces or stones because it looks like it's really cut from piece of wood / stone. here what I found http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/OpenGL:Tutorials:3D_Textures